# Best practice for joinning 2 tables using LIKE operator or better approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-like, data-warehouse

I have 2 tables that have to be processed once a day in data warehouse.

MessageTable

- Id integer primary key
- Message varchar(max)

Example:

```
Id  | Message
 1  | Hi! This is the first message.
 2  | the last message.
```

PartTable

- PartId integer primary key
- Words varchar(100)

Example:

```
PartId | Message
 1     | This
 2     | message, first
 3     | last
```

Table 1 contains messages to be compared with Table 2 in order to know which parts each message is belonged to.

So above example should return like this.

```
Id   | MessageId | PartId
 1   |  1        |  1
 2   |  1        |  2
 3   |  2        |  3
```

Because message(id 1) contains "This" keyword as well as "message" and "first", it can be part of 0 and 1.
When keywords in a part are separated by comma all the keywords need to be found in message irrespective of the order.

Stored procedure I roughly made for this process is like this.

```
INSERT INTO ResultTable(MessageId, PartId)
    SELECT MessageTable.Id as MessageId, PartTable.Id as PartID
     FROM MessageTable m, PartTable p
    WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(VALUE) FROM STRING_SPLIT(p.Word, ',') WHERE CHARINDEX(CONCAT(' ', VALUE, ' '), m.Message) > 0) = (SELECT COUNT(VALUE) FROM STRING_SPLIT(p.Word, ','))
```

This SQL statement seems to work even though I haven't confirmed thoroughly. But this doesn't look like a good practice.

Should I just try to use more relational approach on PartTable like below? Then all the word rows for a part should be found in message to determine message is belonged to the part.

```
 Id | PartId | Word
 1  | 1      | This
 2  | 2      | message
 3  | 2      | last
```

I can create this table using STRING_SPLIT on PartTable or PartTable can be refactored. But I don't see the way to join this table with MessageTable. Also I am expecting there would be a lot of rows in MessageTable.

Can anyone give me any help on this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do words need to be separate words? That is, should "ThisIsThefirstmessage" match partId 2?

Comment: @JamieF No, I am expecting each word to be separated by space. That's why I used CONCAT(' ', VALUE, ' ').

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm . . . You can combine all parts and messages and split the parts into words.  A `where` clause can be used for filtering, so only matches are included.  A final aggregation and counting returns the message/part pairs where all words match:

```
select m.id, pt.partid
from message m cross join
     parttable pt cross apply
     string_split(pt.words, ',') s
where m.message like '%' + s.value + '%'
group by m.id, pt.partid
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from parttable pt2 cross apply
                        string_split(pt.words, ',') s
                   where pt2.partid = pt.partid
                  );
```

This is not efficient and it is very hard to optimize in SQL Server given your data structure.

A better structure for the `parttable` would be an improvement for the query:

```
select m.id, ptn.partid
from message m join
     (select ptn.*, count(*) over (partition by partid) as cnt
      from parttablenormalized ptn 
     ) ptn
     on m.message like '%' + ptn.word + '%'
group by m.id, pnt.partid, cnt
having count(*) = cnt;
```

However performance might not change much.  You would need to denormalize `message` as well for a speedier query.

Comment: Can you please provide me with some example for denomalizing message? MessageTable only contains id and message body. I don't see how to denormalize message.